# Getting InvalidKeyFile while importing ccxt, eospy, libeospy

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, python-3.9, ccxt

I am facing an issue while import ccxt-1.42.7 which is depended on eospy and libeospy.

```
File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ccxt/bullish_nav.py", line 29, in <module>
from eospy.cleos import EOSKey
File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eospy/cleos.py", line 6, in <module>
from .keys import EOSKey, check_wif
File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eospy/keys.py", line 6, in <module>
from .utils import sha256, ripemd160, str_to_hex, hex_to_int
File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eospy/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
from .exceptions import InvalidKeyFile
```

Trying to execute this on docker service  (base image Python:3.9)
OS Info, with Python3.9:

```
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
```

Python Packages:

```
python==3.9
eospy==0.0.2 and libeospy==2.1.0
```

Tried everything, doesn't seems to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Found a solution, just for Knowledge sharing I am keeping this post alive.
turns out eospy and libeospy don't work together and eospy is obsolete, just uninstall eospy and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution regarding this issue, turns out eospy and libeospy are not interacting with each other, and eospy is obsolete, we just need to uninstall eospy and everything works

```
pip uninstall eospy # if using pip
pipenv uninstall eospy # if using pipenv
python -m pip uninstall eospy # another method to do it.
```